# Do access queries automatically get truncated?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

This might have been asked before, but I can't seem to find any relevant answer anywhere.

I wrote a couple of long queries in Access (2003) a couple of weeks ago. I wanted to use those queries today and found that they are been truncated. The query starts as it should and somewhere halfway through it says `AS [%$##@_Alias]` and the rest is missing.

Both query are only a few 100 characters long, so well below the limit allowed by Access.

The structure of both queries is like this

```
SELECT Some calculated fields with a few IIF statements
FROM 
(
    SELECT Some fields calculated with lots of IIF statement
    FROM joined table
    WHERE some condition
)
ORDER BY Some fields
```

Which I do not is particularly demanding of Access, and should certainly not cause it truncate the query in anger. So why does this happen?

Please don't slam me for putting in Japanese text now, the next part is purely for reference. One of my actual (truncated) queries looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    管理番号, 
    種別, 
    IIF(種別TYPE='', OTHER種別TYPE, IIF(種別TYPE='その他','その他' & OTHER種別TYPE,種別TYPE)) AS TYPE
FROM [
    SELECT 
        管理番号,
        IIF(建物か設備_建物,'建物',IIF(建物か設備_設備, '設備', '種別なし')) AS 種別,
        IIF(建物か設備_建物,IIF(建物用途_戸建住宅,'戸建住宅',IIF(建物用途_共同住宅,'共同住宅',IIF(建物用途_教育施設,'教育施設',IIF(建物用途_庁舎,'庁舎',IIF(建物用途_事務所,'事務所',IIF(建物用途_工場,'工場',IIF(建物用途_倉庫,'倉庫',IIF(建物用途_店舗,'店舗',IIF(建物用途_物置小屋,'物置小屋',IIF(建物用途_車庫,'車庫',IIF(建物用途_農作小屋,'農作小屋',IIF(建物用途_その他,'その他')))))))))))),
        IIF(建物か設備_設備,IIF(設備種別_物置,'物置',IIF(設備種別_駐車場,'駐車場',IIF([設備種別_運動場/庭等],'運動場/庭等',IIF(設備種別_電気設備等,'電気設備等',IIF(設備種別_畜舎など,'畜舎など',IIF(設備種別_ﾋﾞﾆｰﾙﾊｳｽ等,'ﾋﾞﾆｰﾙﾊｳｽ等',IIF(設備種別_その他,'その他'))))))),'')) AS 種別TYPE,
        '（' & REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(建物用途_その他記載欄),'(',''),')','') & '）' AS OTHER種別TYPE
    FROM 
        T_メイン INNER JOIN T対象 ON T_メイン.管理番号=T対象.調査番号]. AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

EDIT

I rechecked both of my queries and unlike I said only one of them got truncated. The other one is intact. Extremely weird...

Comment: You're right, if I give it an alias it will work correctly. Seems like an alias is required when saving the query, even if it isn't when the query is executed. Can you please rewrite this as an answer?

Comment: By the way, did you ever notice one of your queries getting cut short after an automatic alias was added?

Comment: No, I haven't seen any part of my SQL text discarded in that situation.  However, that doesn't prove much because I've developed the habit of assigning my own aliases routinely.  Perhaps I might see it if I let the designer add the alias for me more often.  I really don't know.  :-(

Comment: Oki doki. Well, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed that if I don't assign an alias for a subquery, Access' query designer will assign one for me. And those aliases resemble the one you cited, `[%$##@_Alias]`. However, I've not noticed it discard any part of my SQL text when it added such an alias. So although this suggestion may be a long shot, try assigning your own alias, eg `FROM ( ... ) AS sub`, and see whether the query designer preserves the rest of your SQL text.

Comment: +1 I agree, best practice is to alias any derived tables. Makes things a lot simpler if you are using multiples.