# Saved Access Queries randomly truncated to just "SELECT;"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm running MS Access 365 (v16, 32bit).

I've got a saved query and every now and then Access randomly truncates it to just a "SELECT;" and nothing else.

I found this: [Do access queries automatically get truncated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743625/do-access-queries-automatically-get-truncated)

But I don't have sub-queries so it doesn't seem to apply.

Here's an example of a query that keeps getting truncated:

```
SELECT customer_data.Customer_Number, customer_data.customer_data.Customer_Legal_Name, customer_data.Customer_Business_Name, Sum(orders.Count) AS totals
FROM customer_data INNER JOIN orders ON Customer_Number = orders.CustomerId
WHERE (((orders.Date_and_Time)>=[Forms]![MainPage]![Start_Date] And (orders.Date_and_Time)<=[Forms]!                                        
[MainPage]![End_Date]))
GROUP BY customer_data.Customer_Number, customer_data.Customer_Legal_Name, customer_data.Customer_Business_Name;
```

I'm using form data in the query, but I've had it happen with simpler queries.

Anyone ever have this happen or have any idea what's going on? I like using saved queries, but I can't have them just breaking on me like this.

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, never seen that but I am still using Access 2010. Could use `orders.Date_and_Time BETWEEN [Forms]![MainPage]![Start_Date] AND [Forms]!                                        
[MainPage]![End_Date]`

Comment: I do find it odd that Access did not prefix table name to Customer_Number in ON clause.

Comment: Sorry that's on me, I had to scrub some table names off it and left those off. They're prefixed in the actual code.  I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Using Access since version 2, never seen that. Did you try compacting ? Or importing all items in a fresh db ? Looks like a corruption issue. Is the db in a shared folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know but perhaps (if it is not a bug or other kind of problem in your system) adding "`PARAMETERS [Forms]![MainPage]![Start_Date] DateTime, [Forms]![MainPage]![End_Date] DateTime;`" at the beginning of the SQL text